# Changing the opacity of an embedded youtube player uppon click with JS or another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to embed a responsive youtube video player on my wordpress site with some custom youtube parameters and with a different image as thumbnail. I want my video to launch with a single click as well. I tried a lot of things but I can't find a way to finalized my idea. Right now my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel=stylesheet hre=/styles.css>
<style>
.responsive-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 53.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.responsive-container, .responsive-container iframe { max-width: 1280px; max-height: 720px; }
.responsive-container iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    .responsive-container {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);  // IE
    -moz-opacity:0;          // Firefox
    -khtml-opacity: 0;       
    opacity: 0;         
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="responsive-container" >
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="//youtube.com/embed/**VIDEO-ID**?VQ=HD720&rel=0&theme=dark&color=white&autohide=2&modestbranding=1" frameborder="1"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I've set the opacity of the player to 0 because I'm working with the Nimble builder Wordpress plugin and I've set the background of my section to the desired thumbnail.
The only problem is that I want the opacity of my youtube player to go back to 1 uppon click (or touch on mobile devices) so it could replace the background thumbnail on the spot.

I hope I'm understandable...
I guess it's a real newbie question, which I am, but after hours and hours of searches and experiments I still can't figure it out so a bit of help would be genuinely appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As far as i can tell you have not yet tried something yourself or atleast not shown your tries, so i will assume you are looking for a push in the right direction. 
You are probably looking for [EventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an image with a class

```
<img src="/Images/video.png" class="iframePlaceholder">
```

And then add jQuery to replace the image with the iframe onclick

```
 $( '.iframePlaceholder' ).click( function ()
  {
    var video = '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yourcode?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe></div>';
    $( this ).replaceWith( video );
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! It works great when I put this:

https://codeshare.io/GkWXYY

However, the placeholder image is only clickable in editor view in Nimble builder, but if I publish and go back to the site, the image is not clickable anymore and I can't launch the video...

Comment: Try putting the javascript in a custom js file rather than the admin and wrap it in a document.ready function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that with no luck but when I replaced all the $ by jQuery it suddenly worked, strange. Anyway, I sincerly appreciated your help, you saved me from these torments. Have a nice day! :)